# Monitor web API response time in web server level

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, graphite, influxdb

I was trying to measure some metrics (specially response times for different URLs) for my web app that is going to get under some user load. I chose [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.com/) as it can handle large amount of data and integerates nicely with [Grafana](http://grafana.org) (Graphite is also OK for me). I was going to post my reponse times from my flask app into InfluxDB using [influxdb python client](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-python).

I wonder is there a tool or a simple way to fill `InfluxDB` from `NGINX` or `uWSGI` to get better performance and offload them from my python app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to feed performance data from your webserver into `InfluxDB`, there are several ways to do so. I would recommend you the following:

1. Let your webserver log it's requests via syslog
2. Use [`syslog-ng`](https://syslog-ng.org/) to process the logs
3. [`syslog-ng`](https://syslog-ng.org/) can send the data to Graphite: [Link](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-graphite.html)
4. `InfluxDB` has a graphite adapter built-in which can read the graphite protocoll and put the data into `InfluxDB`
5. Use `Grafana` to display your `InflxuDB` data

This is just an example toolchain. You can also use [`CollectD`](https://collectd.org/) to gather your performance metrics and send it to InfluxDB's graphite adapter. But I think the `syslog-ng` solution is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware they can log into syslog without plugins. Seems `NGINX` >= 1.7.1 can do it.